# Combining two RAIDs

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, raid

I have an OSX machine which houses 2 RAIDs made of 6 disks.

The 2 RAIDs contain 6TB of data; they were set up with **Disk Utility**:

- A 'safe' 4TB RAID-1 (mirror) made of 2 x 4TB disks, 3.68TB used
- A 'fast' 8TB RAID-0 (striped) made of 4 x 2TB disks, 2.41TB used

I have 2 spare 4TB disks. I want to create 1 RAID10 of 4 x 4TB disks. Since RAID10, if I'm correct, is a striped set of mirrored sets, can I install the 2 new 4 TB disks, mirror them, then create the RAID10 by striping them together with the *existing* RAID1? (I would then copy the data from the current striped set over to the new RAID10.)

- Will Disk Utility allow this *without* erasing the data? I'm guessing it would have to copy half the data over to the new mirror.

Comment: According to Apple Tech Support, this cannot be done without wiping all 4 disks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. I am not aware of **any** utility, Mac, PC, Linux, whatever that will allow you to convert a RAID volume to another type while adding more disks to the mix.

Your only option is to back up your data, and set up the RAID that you need to, which will wipe the drives.

BTW not sure if Apple supports RAID-10 out of the box, perhaps someone else who knows for sure can chime in. I am thinking probably not.

Comment: I have successfully made RAID 10 with Disk Utility; very easy. Just mirror some drives, then stripe those volumes. And Disk Utility *does* allow non-destructive resizing of a volume; but I don't know if it works with RAID volumes.

Comment: Yah, re-sizing works but here you are modifying the **type** of RAID and I don't believe that works. Unfortunately I don't have a Mac and the drives to test it on...